# what is difference between "throws" with the method name and catching an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I am very new to exception handling in java, hence this question might seems stupid but please let it be answered. Suppose i have a **method A** in which some part of code can throw an **exception B** then what is the difference between catching the exception in the method or writting the method declaration as:-

```
void A() throws B{
     ----//----
     }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The difference lies in the way you call the method.

1. If your method signature says `throws Exception`, the code that calls your method must deal with the `Exception` either by catching it [via a `catch` clause] or throw it back [via `throws` clause].
2. If you `catch` the `Exception`, you are basically trying to handle the `Exception` yourself and the code that calls your method does not have to deal with the `Exception`.

My advice is as follows:

1. If you think you can handle and recover from the `Exception`, that you should `catch` and do the needful.
2. If you cannot deal with the `Exception` properly that do not `catch` it, you must throw it back.

NOTE: It is a bad programming style to `catch` an `Exception` and re-throw it back [although you can do it]. If you wrap the `Exception` with another one, then it is ok. But in this case it must make sense to wrap the Exception with another one.

Update: The idea is, no matter what number of layers your application has, somebody **has** to deal with that `throws Exception` clause. You cannot just let a StackTrace appear to the user in the middle of his activity with the application. The point to consider is "Can you recover from the error and resume your processing?" If yes, then handle the Exception, else throw it back to the layer that can at least show a meaningful message to the user about what happened.

Comment: i guess this is the most satisfactory answer as far now... i also want to ask that my all exceptions(custom) are derived from the same class say for example C, so will it be a good practice that i handle B inside and write "A() throws C" and make the calling method to handle exception C for providing the custom message. Also note that i have "n" numbers of methods having exception B so writting it with throws will be a better idea??? i am confused with the design pattern.

Answer (score 2):

If you catch the exception in `A()` you have to react to the error in your method `A()`, for example by trying the offending code again, logging the error, etc.

If you (re)throw the exception, you expect/forcce the method that called `A()` to handle the exception or it goes unhandled.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that if you catch B in the method body, you're handling the exception. You could throw another exception, but unless you do so the problem is considered solved as far as Java is concerned. By using the `throws` declaration on the method signature, you're indicating that your method can throw exceptions of type B and other pieces of code using it will be forced to deal with it, or throw it further up.

Comment: hi can i use both in my method i want b to be catched and logged, also the wherever this method is been used there also the excetion should be handled???

Comment: You can catch the exception, then simply throw it again in the catch clause: `catch(B b) { throw b; }`. But like Swaranga said, not good style. Also, catching an error, logging it and then throwing it further up (wrapped in another or not) isn't a good idea either, unless the only thing doing logging is that class. Chances are something above also does logging, meaning you get duplicate stack traces in your logs. Very annoying.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote is merely an exception *specification*, which tells everyone which exceptions you may possibly throw. That doesn't mean that you will actually end up throwing any exceptions.

On the other hand, `try`/`catch` is about exception *handling*: You surround code in a try block which may throw an exception and then handle the exceptions as they come in.

From inside your class `A` you are only allowed to throw exceptions which are listed in the exception specification; if `A` derives from another class or interface, `A`s specification must be at least as restrictive as that of the base.

Answer (score 1):

When you throw the exception you are "throwing" it back to the caller of that method.

On the other hand "catching" it with a try-catch block allows you to handle it within the method.

```
try {
//Do your stuff here
}

catch (Exception ex) {
System.out.println("I just caught exception = " + ex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Catching the exception means you handle it, and should be done if you can recover from the exception, or you want to rethrow another exception.

Throwing the exception means letting the caller deal with it, should be used in any other case.

I would suggest you follow [this lesson](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/).

Answer (score 1):

If you catch the exception in the method, you are essentially *handling* it (even if you do nothing with it) and the caller may not (necessarily) be aware; otherwise you are indicating to callers of the method what can go wrong, and what errors they're expected to handle, and if they don't handle it, then their application will certainly make them aware when the exception occurs.

Answer (score 1):

When you are catching the exception it means that you'll handle the exception somehow in your catch-part. But when you are declaring that A() throws B you simply tell that A()-function might throw a B-exception. So when somebody is using A()-function he knows that he must handle the B-exception or throw it forward.

Comment: I believe that yes you can, but I can't imagine reason that you want to do that. When you know that you can handle the exception, you are catching it. But if you don't know how to properly hand the exception you can throw it to the user which calls your function

Answer (score 1):

1. Catching the Exception is: You are providing a placeholder for handling the exceptional situation. 
   So if any part of code in try block throws this exception, it will come to the catch block and the piece of code will be executed.
2. Throwing Exception is : You are not handling the exception. So if the code in the method which throws exception in header, creates the mentioned exception, it will be thrown to the method stack. 
   so if code is like :

> ```
> method1()   {
> x.method2();
>   }
>   method2() {   
>    method3(); 
>   }  
> method3() throws SomeException   {  .....  ......   }
> ```

Then if the code in method3 throws SomeException, that will be propagated to method2, if method2 also does not handle the exception then to method1, likewise, up in the method stack.